# How would I calculate values only from the last 5 years in excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have the following columns:
Col A - Project Title
Col B - Project Month & Year
Col C - Project Cost

My database has more than 5 years' worth of data and will be updated continuously. I would like to calculate the average of the 2 largest project costs over the last 5 years only. How could I do it such that it only reads values from Col B that are only from the most recent 5 years?

My current formula looks something like below (there is some bloat as I've also factored in cases where there would be only 1 or 0 projects, and also removed values deemed as outlier with cell C$652 being the outlier threshold):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$400:C$625,">0")<1,"NA",ROUND(@IF(COUNTIF(C$400:C$625,">0")=1,LARGE(C$400:C$625,{1}),AVERAGE(LARGE(IF(C$400:C$625<=C$652,C$400:C$625),{1}),LARGE(IF(C$400:C$625<=C$652,C$400:C$625),{2}))),1))
```

My issue with the above formula is that it's reading from static cells and will have to be constantly updated, so I'm trying to find a way to optimise the formula such that it automatically only reads values from the past 5 years.

There are no issues with the above formula otherwise and it's returning the expected results.

Thank you in advance to all.

Comment: What version of excel are you using? If Excel for 365 or Excel 2019, you have access to FILTER and LET functions that can help accomplish this

Comment: What format are the dates in? I recommend you provide some sample data in the question, use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables for an easy table.

Comment: Why not use the current date with now() and subtract 5 years to get the window?

Comment: *How could I do it such that it only reads values from Col B that are only from the most recent 5 years?* Maybe you should try filtering or using [Pivot Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)